# How do I find multiple word for 'find' command?

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos

```
find $path1 $path2 -regex '.*\(\.log\|\.err\|\.out\)' -mtime -10 -exec cp "{}" $destination \;
```

This is my command in script to find a filename with extension as shown above. It was success until I found out some of my file contain 'filename.extension.date' which I cannot retrieve it. So I try and error (also using -iname but Im dont understand) to find the file which I want find 'word/string' instead of extension so I can get the file (filename.extension.date & filename.extension).

Comment: What format of *date* to you want to match? YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: the date is not related actually. date can be any format.

Comment: Any format, even `file.log.tar.gz`, `tar.gz` being the date?

Comment: my bad. Yeah some file ended with date is YYYYMMDD

Comment: for example file is:
abc.log
def.log.20221011
qwer.err
qwe.out
jkqwe.out.20211023
so how i can get this file

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and give us some example file names. Make sure to tell us which files should be found and which files should not be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also copy the `.log`/`.err`/`.out` files that have an extra *.date* suffix, and assuming those *date*s are in YYYY-MM-DD format, and assuming GNU `find` (as your regexp suggests you're using), and GNU `cp`, you'd do

```
LC_ALL=C find "$path1" "$path2" \
  -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex '.*\.(log|err|out)(\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})?' \
  -type f \
  -exec cp -t "$distination" {} +
```

Replace `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` with `[0-9]{8}` for YYYYMMDD dates, etc.

The `.*\.(log|err|out)(\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})?` extended regular expression matches on:

- `.*`: any number (`*`) of characters (`.`), which thanks to `LC_ALL=C` means any byte, those bytes not having to form valid characters in the user's locale. Followed by:
- `\.`: a literal `.` (dot / period). Followed by:
- `(log|err|out)`: either `log`, `err` or `out`.
- `(...)?`: an optional (`?`) `...`, `...` being:
- `\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`, a literal `.` again followed by `4` characters in the 0-9 range which thanks to `LC_ALL=C` again is limited to 0123456789, followed by `-`, 2 more of those digits, `-` and 2 more digits.

With BSD `find`, you'd use the `-E` option instead of the `-regextype posix-extended` predicate for the argument to `-regex` to be treated as an extended regexp.

Comment: is it for file with .date or could be any file?and assuming the file is not .date . Maybe .something. Thats why I just want filter 'log', 'err', 'out' only

Comment: @qwerty, the `?` makes the `date` optional. See edit.